# jquery element in viewport + each function

Tags: jquery, each

I'm using a jquery plugin that triggers an event when the monitored element is in/out of the viewport (http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/), and I can get it to work with .addClass or .removeClass, but can't get it working with .each + .fadeIn, my guess is it's a simple syntax error on my part.

Works perfectly:

```
$('#foo .inAndOut').bind('inview', monitor);
function monitor(event, visible)
    {
    if(visible)
    {
      $(this).removeClass('stop').addClass('start');
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).removeClass('start').addClass('stop');
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use this with the following (tested, and working) function:

```
   $("#DIV1, #DIV2, #DIV3").each(function(i) {
         $(this).delay(8000).delay(i*1500).fadeIn();
   });
```

This was tried but doesn't work:

```
$("#DIV1, #DIV2, #DIV3").bind('inview', monitor);
function monitor(event, visible)
    {
    if(visible)
    {
      $("#DIV1, #DIV2, #DIV3").each(function(i) {
          $(this).delay(8000).delay(i*1500).fadeIn();
      });
    }
    else
    {
      alert('out');
    }
}
```

I'm open to anything, including a totally different way of going about this; thank you.

Comment: are you getting any error on console ?

Comment: No console errors. The page loads fine but nothing related to this code does anything.

Comment: Just a tip: You can call `delay` once with `8000 + (i * 1500)`

Comment: I'll use that delay tip; thanks.

Comment: Also, it'll be easier for us to help you solve problems if you provide us with [http://jsfiddle.net] showing your relevant code.

Comment: I've never seen the 'inview' event, i'll google it.

Comment: Seems to be a nice plugin anyway :)

Comment: @gvee It is the index of the each method

Comment: Alright, I made a jsfiddle with the basic working .each function: http://jsfiddle.net/2K3MB/9/. In the meantime I'll go brush up on the :visible property, but from recall I don't think it's an 'in viewport' but rather a 'display:none' vs. 'display:block' which wouldn't serve my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach instead:

```
// Cache elements we're actioning on
var elems = $('#foo, #bar');

// Give them a custom attribute (I've chosen attr() here, but you could use data())
elems.each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('data-inview-index', i);
});

// Now bind the inview stuff
elems.bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    // And we can access the custom attribute for use here.
    var i = $(this).attr('data-inview-index');

    if (visible) {
        $(this).text(i);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/p7jDg/2/

Using `.data()`: http://jsfiddle.net/p7jDg/3/

Comment: Jesus. This is a bit over my head, but I'll try to get this working with the fiddle I posted; thank you, I'm always blown away by people's helpfulness.

Comment: Alright, I've got your code working in a jsfiddle, but .each + .slideDown fires off whether it's in the viewport or not. I need it to only fire off if in view, and to stop firing off when taken out of view. Work in progress: http://jsfiddle.net/yVrC6/20/

Comment: OK, I'm very, very close to getting this to work; see: http://jsfiddle.net/yVrC6/58/. I'm just not use how to pause/resume the .each + .slideDown when the thing leaves the view (time to pause) and then re-enters the view (resume where you left off).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yVrC6/145/ I've changed your `else` condition to `inviewSlider.stop().fadeOut();`. This will ensure that the queue is cleared on all the elements at once.